# How can I synchronize the class so that I can use from UI thread and background threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I have a utility class as follows:

```
public class MetaUtility {
   private static final SparseArray<MetaInfo> metaInfo = new SparseArray<>();  

   public static void flush() {  
      metaInfo.clear();  
   }   

   public static void addMeta(int key, MetaInfo info) {  
     if(info == null) {  
         throw new NullPointerException();  
     }  
     metaInfo.append(key, info);  
   }  

   public static MetaInfo getMeta(int key) {  
       return metaInfo.get(key);  
   }  
}
```

This class is very simple and I wanted to have a "central" container to be used across classes/activities.
The issue is threading.
Right now it is populated (i.e the `addMeta` is called) only in 1 place in the code (not in the UI thread) and that is not going to change.
The getter is accessed by UI thread and in some cases by background threads.
Carefully reviewing the code I don't think that I would end up with the case that the background thread would add elements to the sparse array while some other thread would try to access it.
But this is very tricky for someone to know unless he knew the code very well.
My question is, how could I design my class so that I can safely use it from all threads including UI thread?
I can't just add a synchronized or make it block because that would block the UI thread. What can I do?

Comment: "*I can't just add a synchronized or make it block because that would block the UI thread*" => a call to the method should be very quick so unless you have a queue of thousands of calls waiting, you won't block for more than a few microseconds... If you want non-blocking concurrency you can also replace the SparseArray by a ConcurrentHashMap but I don't know if the performance will be as good. Or you could use lock objects and `tryLock()` for a short period of time and return if the lock couldn't be acquired.

Comment: @assylias:No I will not have have too many threads accessing it. But besides the actual work in the method (which in my case is an O(1) operation) synchronized also implies thread scheduling, and all the CPU housekeeping. Wouldn't that cause an issue to the UI thread?

Comment: @assylias: I also was thinking to check if the caller thread is not UI thread and then synchronize or something like that. Not sure how to do it properly

Comment: based on your first comment (low contention), it seems that simply synchronizing the methods (the three of them) should be fine and the synchronized block will not block the UI thread in any noticeable way.

Comment: @assylias:So the fact that via synchronized the thread scheduler is called the thread is pre-empted from the CPU saving the registers etc the other thread comes in starts execution etc is not likely to cause a problem to the UI thread? This has an impact right?

Comment: I don't think it would be noticeable - if you think it could be an issue you can synchronize the methods and call them from the UI thread using an AsyncTask.

Comment: @assylias:I don't know if it can be an issue tbh. Also I would like to access the getter directly from the UI thread and somehow deal with the other access. I find it weird if I do an async task just to call get in the on background. The code will be even more complex in all the getter places

Comment: `synchronized` does not imply anything about thread scheduling, and I'm not sure what "CPU housekeeping" would mean here. `synchronized` just means mutually-exclusive access is guaranteed. (The JMM says a bunch of other things too, but nothing related to thread scheduling.) Unless your data structure operates slowly it's unlikely the UI thread will be noticeably affected.

Comment: mutually exclusive access means some thread need to leave the running queue and go to the blocked queue and release CPU while some other thread need to get the CPU and run. This is overhead right?

Answer (score 1):

You should just synchronize on your object, because what your class is right now is just a wrapper class around a SparseArray.  If there are thread level blocking issues, they would be from misuse of this object (well, I guess class considering it only exposes public static methods) in some other part of your project.

Comment: But what can I do to not block UI?

Comment: Are we saying for the "getMeta" call?    That's not something you would need to worry about unless your dataset is very large.  SparseArray uses binary search internally, so it's a quick operation unless you're using it horribly wrong somehow.

Comment: You mean something like: `MetaInfo result = null; synchronized(metaInfo){ result = metaInfo.get(key); return result;`? Why is it better than adding synchronized in the signature?

Comment: If you set your respective thread priorities (i.e. background threads being set as such), it shouldn't cause much of an issue.

Comment: Also, either works, there's not a difference really at that point other than syntax.

Answer (score 1):

First shoot can be with `synchronized`.

> @Jim What about the thread scheduling latency?

Android scheduler is based on Linux and it is known as a completely fair scheduler (CFS). It is "fair" in the sense that it tries to balance the execution of tasks not only based on the priority of the thread but also by tracking the amount of execution time that has been given to a thread.

If you'll see "Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread", then need some optimisations.

Comment: Where would I see the `Skipped xx frames`?

Comment: You can see it in Logcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have uncontended lock you should not be afraid of using `synchronized`. In this case lock should be `thin`, which means that it would not pass blocked thread to `OS` scheduler, but would try to acquire lock again a few instructions after. But if you still would want to write non-blocking implementation, then you could use `AtomicReference` for holding the `SparseArray<MetaInfo>` array and update it with `CAS`.

The code might be smth like this:

```
static AtomicReference<SparseArray<MetaInfo>> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();

public static void flush() {
    atomicReference.set(new SparseArray<MetaInfo>);
}

public static void addMeta(int key, MetaInfo info) {
    if(info == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    do {
        SparseArray<MetaInfo> current = atomicReference.get();
        SparseArray<MetaInfo> newArray = new SparseArray<MetaInfo>(current); 
        // plus add a new info 
    } while (!atomicReference.compareAndSet(current, newArray));
}

public static MetaInfo getMeta(int key) {
    return atomicReference.get().get(key);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example code with this `CAS` technique?

Comment: This answer feels a bit like handing a sharp knife to a toddler... it's very easy to get lock-free data structures wrong, often in subtle ways. It would be wiser to find an appropriate class in `java.util.concurrent`. (I think the first part of your answer -- don't be afraid of `synchronized` -- is the right answer in this case.) For a very brief introduction to the subject see http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html , or visit http://jcip.net/ for the detailed version.

Comment: Very interesting answer. Could you please elaborate a bit about the `addMeta`? I am not sure I get the implications